# Which mode recreate, writes and reads while opening a file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My understanding of the the documentation is that `w` writes and truncates first while `+` updates (reads and writes):

```py
f=open("/tmp/f",mode="tw+")
f.write("foo\nbar")
f.readlines() #returns empty list? What am I missing?
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mode `r+` will read/write without truncating and `w+` will read/write with truncating first.

What you're missing is the fact that after writing, your file position is at the end of the file. If you'll use `f.seek(0)` after writing, you'll be able to read just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Reading and writing share the same file position pointer. So after you write, you need to back up to read what you've written. Otherwise, it starts reading from the position that writing ended, and there's nothing there to read.

```
f=open("/tmp/f",mode="tw+")
f.write("foo\nbar")
f.seek(0)
f.readlines() #returns empty list? What am I missing?
```